# Shiny flexdashboard conditional reactive UI elements within modules?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

Suppose I have the following `flexdashboard`; here's the minimal reproducible example:

````
---
title: "TestApp"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: ["bootstrap"]

runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}

# Setup function
setup <- function(input, output, session) {
  return(input)
}

# Server module 
server <- function(input, output, session, setup) {
  output$tabOneTable <- renderTable({
    switch(setup$something,
           'a' = mtcars,
           'b' = iris,
           'c' = rock)
  })

  output$tabTwoTable <- renderTable({
    switch(setup$something2,
           'd' = CO2,
           'e' = iris)
  })

  output$selectSymbol <- renderUI({
    .choices <- switch(setup$something2,
                       'd' = c("Mississippi", "Quebec"),
                       'e' = c("setosa","virginica","versicolor"))
    selectInput(session$ns("reactiveSymbol"), label = NULL, choices = .choices, selected = NULL, width = '100%')
  })

}

# UI modules
tabOneTableUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tableOutput(ns("tabOneTable"))
}

tabTwoTableUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tableOutput(ns("tabTwoTable"))
}

sidebarUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    helpText("Select something:"),  # Note: helpText() looks a little cleaner versus using the 'label' parameter in selectInput() below
    selectInput(ns("something"), label = NULL, choices = c('a','b','c'), selected = NULL, width = '100%')
  )
}

sidebarUI2 <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    helpText("Select something:"),
    selectInput(ns("something2"), label = NULL, choices = c('d','e'), selected = NULL, width = '100%'),
    helpText("Select something else:"),
    uiOutput(ns("selectSymbol"))
  )
}

```

Tab1 {data-icon="fa-bar-chart fa-fw"}
=====================================

Inputs {.sidebar data-width=250}
-------------------------------------

```{r}
globalInputs <- callModule(setup, "inputs")
callModule(server, "main", globalInputs)
sidebarUI("inputs")  # To-do: add sidebar parameter inputs & 'Refresh' chart functionality
```

Row 
-------------------------------------

### {.no-title}

```{r}
tabOneTableUI("main")
```

Tab2 {data-icon="fa-calculator fa-fw"}
=====================================

Inputs {.sidebar data-width=250}
-------------------------------------

```{r}
sidebarUI2("inputs")
```

Row 
-------------------------------------

### {.no-title}

```{r}
tabTwoTableUI("main")
```
````

The first tab is trivial. Select an option, and it renders a standard HTML table.

My tab 2 isn't working right. For tab 2, this is the functionality I want to achieve:

- On page load, render the table with the selected dataset (note, the `switch`; `'d' = CO2, 'e' = iris`)
- Upon selecting the first option, it should render a second `selectInput` with the `choices` based on the 1st select input. So, if you selected `d`, it would show: `Mississippi` and `Quebec` as options in the 2nd dropdown.
- Then, I want to filter the rendered table, based on the second `selectInput`. So, if you had selected `d`, it would filter the `CO2` dataset based on the `Type` column, and if you had selected `e`, it would filter the `iris` dataset on the `Species` column.

Currently in the above example, my 2nd `selectInput` on the second tab isn't even showing up. What am I doing wrong? And how can I achieve the functionality outlined above?

Thanks in advance!